# optparse-applicative: Generate usage information with custom error message from options definition

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments

I am populating an `Opts` type with constructor `SrvOpts` that stores the command-line arguments:

```
main :: IO ()
main = join $ customExecParser cf $ info options
           (fullDesc <> header "header" <> footer "footer")
    where cf = defaultPrefs { prefShowHelpOnError=True }

options :: Parser (IO ())
options = subparser $
    command "serve" (info (handleServe <$> (SrvOpts
            <$> strOption [...]
```

The function `handleServe` takes the data and then does some further validation.

How can I terminate the program with a custom error message and normal *optparse-applicative*-style usage information generated from `options` from inside `handleServe`?

Comment: Do you always want to terminate your program? Or do you just want to show usage/help information if the user uses a wrong argument or `-h`?

Comment: **After** parsing I'm checking if given strings are in correct format and want to terminate with a normal error message and usage information based on `options` if they are not. Argument handling/parsing is working fine.

Comment: If you are checking the format of the strings individually, you could achieve this by defining your own [ReadM](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.12.1.0/docs/Options-Applicative-Builder.html#t:ReadM) and using it with `option` (instead of using `strOption`).

Comment: @ben-james: OK, but what if I have more complex checks that depend on other values not yet parsed? Isn't there a way to render a "standard error + usage info" generated from `options` from outside the applicative `options` definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using the `parserFailure` function from `Options.Applicative.Extra`:

```
renderError :: Context -> String -> IO ()                                       
renderError c msg = handleParseResult . Failure $                               
                        parserFailure argPrefs argInfo (ErrorMsg msg) [c]
```

In the current version 0.12.0.1 `Context` has to be imported from `Options.Applicative.Internal`, this will change. `Context` constructor takes name of subparser and `ParserInfo` (the `info (handleServe <$> ...` part) that is used to render usage information.